# Is there any way for injecting snippets before the javascript executed by browser?

Tags: javascript

when you visite a website,the browser will fetch necessary resource like html, css and js.Then, the browser will resolve html, execute js code...
I wonder if I can change the behavior of the website by inserting a custom JS fragment into the JS file fetched from the server before the browser executes the JS code?

Comment: You can do this by writing browser extensions.

Comment: you can sequence the execution of javascript. you can execute Javascript before `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <script>
     // Here goes your JS code
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    The content of the document
    </body>
    
    </html>
```